# Send many byte array from server to UWP as a stream

Tags: wcf, camera, uwp, stream

I have a WCF service that updates the byte array from camera continuous like this:

```
private void ImageGrabbedCamera(object sender, ImageGrabbedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.GrabResult.GrabSucceeded)
                {
                    //This variable is updated continuous from the camera
                    result = e.GrabResult.Clone();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And I call this method from the UWP client app to get the byte array from the server

```
public Stream GetStreamCamera()
        {
            MemoryStream ms;
            if (result != null)
            {
                ms = new MemoryStream(ObjectToByteArray(result.PixelData as byte[]));
                ms.Position = 0;
                return ms;
            }
            else
            {
                return new MemoryStream();
            }
        }
```

In client app, I call **while(true)** to **GetStreamCamera()** method to get the frame but it not OK because the capacity is very big and it's not only 1 camera, it about **10 cameras** with resolution **(1280 * 960)**. So do we have any protocol that UWP support to stream the image from the server to UWP client?
I don't want to call **while(true)** to get 1 frame/call anymore.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your issue. Did you mean you want other ways to stream image from server to UWP client instead of WCF service? Have you tried `StreamSocket`?

Comment: yes, that's what I want. StreamSocket don't have way to read continuous, we have to call while(true) like what MSFT wrote on their sample